# R, rgl, plotting points and ellipses

Tags: r, plot, rgl

I am using R to visualize some data.  I am found RGL to be a great library for plotting points.

```
points3d(x,y,z)
```

where x = c(x1,x2, ...), y = c(y1,y2,...), z = c(z1,z2, ...) and x,y,z have the same length, is a great function for plotting large sets of data.

Now, I would like to plot ellipses, mixed in with the data.  I have a characterization of ellipses by a center point C, a vector describing the major axis U, and a vector describing the minor axis V.  I obtain points P on the boundary of the ellipse by

```
P = U*cos(t) + V*sin(t) (t ranges between 0 and 2*pi)
```

obtaining vectors, xt, yt, and zt.  Then I can plot the ellipse with

```
polygon3d(xt,yt,zt)
```

It works fine, but I'm guessing everyone reading is cringing, and will tell me that this is a bad way to do this.  Indeed it takes a couple seconds to render each ellipse this way.

I don't think the ellipse3d function from the RGL package works here; at the very least, I am not working a matrix of covariances, nor do I understand how to get the ellipse I want from this function.  Also, it returns an ellipsoid, not an ellipse.

********** EDIT ****************

For a concrete example that takes awhile:

```
library(rgl)
open3d()

td <- c(0:359)
t <- td*pi/180

plotEllipseFromVector <- function(c,u,v){
    xt <- c[1] + u[1]*cos(t) + v[1]*sin(t)
    yt <- c[2] + u[2]*cos(t) + v[2]*sin(t)
    zt <- c[3] + u[3]*cos(t) + v[3]*sin(t)
    polygon3d(xt,yt,zt) 
}
```

Input center point, major, and minor axis you want.  It takes just over 2 seconds for me.
On the other hand, if I change t to be 0,20,40,... 340, then it works quite fast.

Comment: Oh, I should note, I am making 360 samples (1 for each degree of t) on the boundary.  If I take 20 degree intervals, the speed is pretty good.  But I am still curious if there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you provide some example data and code we can use to time against?

Comment: See edit.  I don't think you need any data to time against.  The time issue is drawing a single ellipse.  Inputting a center such as c=c(1,2,3) and major vector u=c(3,6,2) and minor vector v=c(2,1,2), should exemplify.